# Show top level comments ordered by number of replies

Tags: loop, comments

I am trying to modify the comment loop  initiated by wp_list_comments to change the order they are returned.

Specifically I have 2 levels enabled on my comments (top level and replies), and I want to sort the comments to have the comments with the most replies on top.